# Android, Image from URI

Tags: android, uri, android-image

I want to set image for ImageView based on the photo of the contact that I choose from the list of contacts. After starting an appriopriate intent, in OnActivityResult I call the `setImageURI()` method as following:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==SHOW_CONTACTS_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Log.d("Selection",data.toString());
                contactImage.setImageURI(getImageUri(data.getData()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the `getImageUri()` method:

```
private Uri getImageURI(Uri uri) {
        Uri uriToPhoto=null;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor= contentResolver.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            uriToPhoto = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI)));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return uriToPhoto;
    }
```

This method produces Uri like this:
[image]

The problem is that the photo is not being set.
I've tried some tricks with previously calling the `settingImageURI` with null paramater or invalidating contactImage after calling the method, as suggested in different threads, but it's not going to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `setImageURI()` has other problems, notably doing the `ContentProvider` I/O on the main application thread. I would use an image loading library like Picasso or Universal Image Loader, handing them the `PHOTO_URI` value and the `ImageView`, and letting them populate the `ImageView` asynchronously, using a placeholder image in the meantime.

Comment: Try to convert the Uri you get to a filepath and go to the path to see whether the image exists. or Use new File(uri.getAbosolutePath) to judge.

Comment: @tinysunlight There's no such method like getAbsolutePath available. I can only use getPath() that returns the string, but how can I "go to the path" to see if it exists?

Comment: is a path. just go file explorer in phone and turn in the path.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question isn't quite straightforward. Actually, there was nothing wrong with the code. It started working after switching from the API 23 to API 21 and changing my last emulator.

Then I guess it must have been something with those new permissions in Marshmallow.